# Jquery autocomplete breaks on ampersand or single quote

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to use JQuery's Autocomplete feature as follows:

```
<form name="form_data" action="#" method="post">
      <label for="plp_who">Pick Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="plp_who" id="plp_who" class="form-control compact" value="">
</form>

 $('##plp_who').autocomplete({source: "/autocomplete/legacy_contact.cfm",minLength: 2});
```

`"legacy_contact.cfm"` searches a database and returns a list of results in `JSON` format.  When that list contains a single quote or an ampersand the control fails to respond, even if I escape the character.  By "fail" I mean that the control does not give any indication that results were returned, though no Javascript error is thrown.

For example:

```
[ {"label" : "Bob Michelucci, Rossi\'s Pop Up Marketplace", "value" : "9338"} ]
```

**fails**

```
[ {"label" : "Bob Michelucci, Rossis Pop Up Marketplace", "value" : "9338"} ]
```

**succeeds**

```
[ {"label" : "Brian Wright, R\&B Contracting \& Excavation", "value" : "8694"} ]
```

**fails**

```
[ {"label" : "Brian Wright, R and B Contracting  and  Excavation", "value" : "8694"} ]
```

**succeeds**

Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong?  I can't believe that there is no way to encode these characters so that they do not break the control, but trying to escape them using & or ' will not work because, of course, it contains an ampersand.

Comment: Did you ever identify a fix? Still working on it?

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to replicate the issue with the "failed" data. Appears to work:

```js
var myData = [{
  "label": "Bob Michelucci, Rossi\'s Pop Up Marketplace",
  "value": "9338"
}, {
  "label": "Brian Wright, R\&B Contracting \& Excavation",
  "value": "8694"
}];

$(function() {
  $('#plp_who').autocomplete({
    source: myData,
    minLength: 2
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form name="form_data" action="#" method="post">
  <label for="plp_who">Pick Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="plp_who" id="plp_who" class="form-control compact" value="">
</form>
```

Considering that you're pulling the data from a CFM, you may consider passing looking at the actual response from the CFM via Console or Network tools. You can also test this manually. Navigate to your page, with a test like 'bo':

```
/autocomplete/legacy_contact.cfm?term=bo
```

You should receive an array of object results.